# mecabをJavaScriptから実行したい

Tags: javascript, mecab

mecabをコマンドプロンプトから実行はできるのですが、他の言語から実行する方法がわかりません。javascriptから実行したいと考えております。
最終的には、javascriptからmecabを実行し、htmlを形態素解析して他のファイルに出力する、ということをやりたいです。

windows10(x64)です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 環境も記載するといいかと思います。`編集`から質問文を編集し追記してください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[node-mecab-async](https://github.com/hecomi/node-mecab-async)というNode.js 用モジュールがあります。試してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。まだ初心者でよくわかっていない事も多いのですが、調べてみるとnode.jsはサーバーサイドで動作するものと思うのですが、今回はクライアントサイドで完結させたいです。ローカルフォルダ内のhtmlファイルを解析したいと考えています。説明不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: mecabはC++で書かれたアプリケーションなので、ブラウザー上では動作しませんが。。。。

Comment: mecabはC++で実装されているようです。node.js用などのバインディングライブラリが必要になります。そのため、ブラウザ 上で動くクライアントサイドのみでは利用できないと思います。mecabではなく、javascriptのみで実装された他の形態素解析器を調査すべきだと思います。

Comment: そうなんですか！ありがとうございます。他の解析器を調査してみます。

Comment: @kooooji 分かち書きくらいならJavaScriptでも出来るでしょうが形態素解析を行うなら辞書が必須です。クライアントで辞書検索させるくらいならサーバで処理させて非同期で取得した方がいいかと思います。